# Cygwin - Eric6 installer cannot find qscintilla2, which was installed via cygwin setup

Tags: cygwin

I am new to Cygwin, using it in order to learn Python. I am attempting to install Eric6 Python IDE, which requires certain packages such as PyQt5, Scintilla2, etc.

I installed python2, python3, PyQt5, pip3.6 (pip-9.0.3), and several other packages using the Cygwin setup app (setup-x86_64.exe).

When I attempt to install Eric6:

```
$ python3 install.py
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.6.4
Found PyQt5
Found pyuic5
Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and
its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper.
Error: cannot import name 'Qsci'
```

### Update

Per matzeri's answer, I found that I had missed seeing scintilla2 in the Cygwin packages list, so I installed it from there `[package: mingw64-x86_64-qscintilla2-qt5]` and it appeared to install without any issues. However, I continue to get the exact same error as before when attempting to install Eric6 `Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper. Error: cannot import name 'Qsci'`

I have tried rebooting both Cygwin and the local machine, with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

install `qscintilla2` from cygwin setup. Before installing anything from pip you should check if the package is already available in cygwin. See

https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

for the full list.
For QT5 you should install:

```
libqscintilla2_qt5-common   
libqscintilla2_qt5-devel    
libqscintilla2_qt5_13
qscintilla2
```

Comment: Hi Matzeri - thanks very much for the suggestion +1. You were right, I had missed seeing qscintilla2 in the Cygwin packages list (I was looking alphabetically but it was under "mingw64-x86_64-qscintilla2-qt5"). And it installed fine using Cygwin setup. However, even after rebooting computer I continue to have the same error message from Eric6 installer (about qscintilla2 not being installed - but this time it is installed)

Comment: `mingw64-x86_64-qscintilla2-qt5` is for cross compilation from `cygwin` to `mingw64-x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

After installing qscintilla2 from CygWin's setup

> package: mingw64-x86_64-qscintilla2-qt5 (QT Scintilla editor class for Win64 toolchain)

as recommended by Matzeri, I then also installed these two packages:

> mingw64-x86_64-qscintilla2-qt4 (QT Scintilla editor class for Win64 toolchain)
>
> python3-pyqt5-qsci (Scintilla editor class for QT4)

After installing [mingw64-x86_64-qscintilla2-qt4] the problem continued as before, but as soon as I installed [python3-pyqt5-qsci], I was able to re-run the setup

> python3 install.py

and it completed successfully

[image: Eric 6 install completed successfully]

---

### UPDATE:

Eric6 was not the best development environment for Python under Windows. I found these other two that work great and do not require Cygwin or any other special environment -- they work under Windows, *comme il faut*:

[Pyscripter](https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter) - Fantastic IDE, dev team responds quickly and seriously considers bug reports and feature requests, step-thru debugger, really great debug/variable windows that can be dragged onto a second monitor, pip install system hasn't failed me yet. *(Caution: uses Ctrl+Y as delete line instead of redo, but dev has assured me that this will be fixed in next update.)*

[VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) - open source IDE by Microsoft that essentially duplicates Visual Studio. Many strengths, but more difficult to watch global variables.